Any downsides of using UTF8 collation in SQL Server 2019?
We have some columns in the table that could possibly get some non-ANSI characters and we must store them. Before the SQL Server 2019 there was the only 1 option - NVARCHAR data type, however starting with SQL Server 2019 it is possible to use VARCHAR data type with the collations that ends with %_UTF8. I understand that for full compatibility with the size, I'll need to double the VARCHAR columns size, so if it was VARCHAR(20) it will needed to be VARCHAR(40) to cover the case if somebody would insert text where all the 20 characters are non-ANSI, but are there any other downsides of such collation? The data in that column will be ~99.9% with ANSI characters only.


I understand that for full compatibility with the size, I'll need to double the VARCHAR column's size

You might need to do more than that, depending on the characters you have or will be storing. As the documentation says:


With UTF-8 encoding, characters in the ASCII range (000000–00007F) require 1 byte, code points 000080–0007FF require 2 bytes, code points 000800–00FFFF require 3 bytes, and code points 0010000–0010FFFF require 4 bytes.


For example, SELECT DATALENGTH('') returns 4 using a UTF8 collation, but LEN returns 1.
and (emphasis added)


It's a common perception, in CHAR(n) and VARCHAR(n) or in NCHAR(n) and NVARCHAR(n), that n defines the number of characters. This is because, in the example of a CHAR(10) column, 10 ASCII characters in the range 0–127 can be stored by using a collation such as Latin1_General_100_CI_AI, because each character in this range uses only 1 byte.
However, in CHAR(n) and VARCHAR(n), n defines the string size in bytes (0–8,000), and in NCHAR(n) and NVARCHAR(n), n defines the string size in byte-pairs (0–4,000). n never defines numbers of characters that can be stored.




are there any other downsides of such collation

Every change comes with risk, which is mitigated by testing.
Your code and applications might not be ready to deal with characters having a variable 1–4-byte length. Some of your T-SQL in particular might make assumptions using DATALENGTH. You might also need to review those built-in functions that don't fully support Supplementary Characters (though most do now).
UTF-8 support is relatively new, so you might encounter bugs that don't exist with decades-old collations. I don't recall hearing any particular horror stories offhand.
Having a column collation that is different from the database (and tempdb!) default collation can also expose collation comparison issues that were masked by the previously uniform situation.
